# Tomcat Websockets Across Multiple Servers

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat8, tomcat8.5

#### Current Solution

I have a Java server (Tomcat) setup issue that I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance on.  Currently my web application is a single-server that has a Java backend running on Tomcat 8.5.  To handle Websocket connections, I keep a `Map` of all the `javax.websocket.Session` passed in the `onOpen()` method.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/status")
public class StatusMessenger
{   
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws Exception
    {
        String sessionId = session.getRequestParameterMap().get("sessionId").get(0);
        sessions.put(session.getId(), session);
    }
```

My application only broadcasts messages to all users, so the `broadcast()` in my code simply loops through `sessions.values()` and sends the message through each `javax.websocket.Session`.

```
public static void broadcast(String event, String message)
{
    for (Session session: sessions.values())
    {
       // send the message
    }
}
```

1. I'm not even sure that's the correct way to handle Websockets in Tomcat, but it's worked for me for years, so I assume it's acceptable.

#### The Problem

I want to now horizontally scale out my application on AWS to multiple servers.  For the most part my application is stateless and I store the regular HTTP session information in the database.  My problem is this static `Map` of `javax.websocket.Session` - it's not stateless, and there's a different `Map` on each server, each with their own list of `javax.websocket.Session`s.

In my application, the server code in certain situations will need to broadcast out a message to all the users.  These events may happen on any server in this multi-server setup.  The event will trigger the `broadcast()` method which loops through the `javax.websocket.Session`s.  However, it will only loop through the sessions in it's own `Map`.

How do I get the multi-server application to broadcast this message to all websocket connections stored across all the servers in the setup?  The application works fine on a single-server (obviously) because there's only 1 list of websocket sessions.  In other words, how do I write a stateless application that needs to store the websocket connections so it can communicate with them later?

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 alternative solutions for this...

1. In my load balancer I put a rule to route all paths with /{my websocket server path} to 1 server so that all the Sessions were on the same server.
2. Use a 3rd party web push library like Pusher (http://pusher.com)